# In Julia, can one write what in Haskell terminology are called "sections?"

Tags: haskell, filter, julia, anonymous-function, sections

---

According to [**A Gentle Introduction to Haskell**](https://www.haskell.org/tutorial/functions.html) …

> In Haskell the partial application of an infix operator is called a section.

Consider the Haskell expression `filter (\n -> n > 0) [-3,-4,5,6,-7,8]`, which evaluates to `[5,6,8]` .

Using a ***section***, this may be re-written in Haskell as `filter (>0) [-3,-4,5,6,-7,8]` .

In ***Julia***, one may write `filter( n -> n > 0, [-3,-4,5,6,-7,8] )` .

Can this last be re-written in Julia using an equivalent of the Haskell section `(>0)` ?

The following yields a syntax error …

```
filter( (>0), [-3,-4,5,6,-7,8] )
```

---

##### Update

Also, in Haskell one can re-write …

> `filter (\list -> length list > 2) [ [2,3], [5,7,11], [13], [17,19,23,29] ]`

… as …

> `filter ((>2).length) [ [2,3], [5,7,11], [13], [17,19,23,29] ]`

In ***Julia***, can one similarly re-write, using a section and function composition?

---

Comment: If you flip `(>0)` to the equivalent `(0<)` then it's just partial application of a two-argument curried function (which happens to be in infix form), i.e. `(<) 0`. This can be done with any curried function. So the question is then just "can Julia curry infix operators?"

Comment: Julia doesn't curry at all. But one can, manually, write curried methods of functions (i.e., overloads that do the currying).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

For your first exemple, you can write:

```
julia> filter(>(0), [-3,-4,5,6,-7,8])
3-element Vector{Int64}:
 5
 6
 8
```

This works because according to the help:

```
julia> ?
help?> >
>(x)

  Create a function that compares its argument to x using >, i.e. a function equivalent to y -> y > x. The returned function is of type Base.Fix2{typeof(>)}, which can be used to implement specialized methods.

  │ Julia 1.2
  │
  │  This functionality requires at least Julia 1.2.
```

So if you want something similar for your second exemple, you may need to define yourself a similar function like this:

```
julia> length_sup(x) = y -> length(y) > x
length_sup (generic function with 1 method)
```

And then you can do:

```
julia> filter(length_sup(2), [ [2,3], [5,7,11], [13], [17,19,23,29] ])
2-element Vector{Vector{Int64}}:
 [5, 7, 11]
 [17, 19, 23, 29]
```

However, whether it is a good idea or not to create custom functions just for some sugar-syntaxing will be up to you. You may eventually want to code macro to simplify this task.

Answer (score 1):

Not syntactically, no.  But some operators have methods for partial application of the "logical" argument, among these all the comparison operators from Base:

```
julia> >(0)
(::Base.Fix2{typeof(>), Int64}) (generic function with 1 method)

julia> filter(>(0), [-3,-4,5,6,-7,8])
3-element Vector{Int64}:
 5
 6
 8
```

However, one is free to write macros that implement some syntactic tricks.  E.g., from [Underscores.jl](https://github.com/c42f/Underscores.jl):

```
@_ people |> filter(_.age > 40, __) |> map(_.name, __)
```